# Function for tracking trading operations with stock

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, analytics

I have the df with Date, open prices of the stock, buy and sell indicators. I need to make a function that could count all these operations with my budget.

```
    Date        Open       Buy Sell
0   2019-08-27  36.270000   1   0
1   2019-10-11  31.740000   0   1
2   2020-03-18  28.320000   1   0
3   2020-06-03  41.380001   0   1
4   2020-11-12  61.610001   1   0
5   2020-12-02  69.120003   0   1
6   2021-03-24  64.500000   1   0
7   2021-06-07  67.269997   0   1
```

So if I have 1 in Buy column I need to buy stocks with all the money in budget. After it I need to sell all at open price where df['Buy'] == 0.
I have tried to create such but it's wrong and I don't have a clue how to fix it.

```
def profit(x):
    budget = 100000
    stocks = 0
    for i in df['Buy_ind']:
        if x == 1:
            budget = budget % df['Open'][i]
            stocks = budget // df['Open'][i]
        if x == 0:
            budget += stocks * df['Open'][i]
    return i
profit()
```

Comment: Please provide the community with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In order to understand what do you expect from budget and stocks, please add them as columns to your data frame and show the values you expect to get for them in row by row basis.

Comment: @MarcelloChiuminatto As you can see in me code, budget = 100000. Also I trade only one stock with the prices that you can see in df['Open'].  I want to crate function that could count my budget  after buying and selling this stock and save it in the list. stock = 0 means that in the begining  I have no stock and 019-08-27 I buy 100000//31.74 stocks

Answer (score 1):

A simple version, cross validated with excel, but check anyways.:

```
import pandas as pd

df_stock = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['8/27/2019','10/11/2019','3/18/2020','6/3/2020','11/12/2020','12/2/2020','3/24/2021','6/7/2021'],
 'Open':[36.27,31.74,28.32,41.380001,61.610001,69.120003,64.5,67.269997,],  
'Buy':[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
'Sell':[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
})


def profit(df, budget):
    stocks = 0
    for idx, r in df.iterrows():
        if r['Buy'] ==1:
            stocks = round(budget//r['Open'],3)
            budget = round(budget%r['Open'] , 3)
            print(f'Buy {stocks} stocks at ', round(r['Open'],3), f'Remaining budget {budget}')

        if r['Sell'] == 1:
            budget = round(stocks*r['Open'] + budget,3)
            stocks = 0
            print('Sold at ', round(r['Open'],3), 'new budget is ', budget)
            
    return budget


print(df_stock)
print('')

profit(df_stock, 10000)

**Output**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdJWu.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
budget = 100000
stocks = 0
for inx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Buy'] == 1:   
        stocks = budget // row['Open']
        budget = budget % row['Open']
    if row['Buy'] == 0:
        budget += stocks * row['Open']
display(budget)
```

The answer was simple. I just didn't know how to work with each row in df: 'for inx, row' - is easy solution.